# Create subsite in another site collection using event recievers

Tags: event-receivers, site-collection, sandbox-solution

I am trying  to create a subsite in another site collection using an event receiver on a list from current site collection. How do I do that?

I have tried getting the context of the target site collection but that is not possible and it throws an exception.

I am using sandbox solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a pure Sandboxed solution this is not possible. A sandboxed solution has absolutely no access outside the current site collection, that's the whole point of sandboxed solutions.

**On-premises**
If you're solution is developed for on-premises SharePoint where it's "just" politics which require the solution to be Sandboxed. Then there is the possibility of someone who is allowed to develop Farm Solutions can develop a [Full-Trust Proxy Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg622618%28v=office.14%29.aspx) which can create the site in the other site collection and allows you to call it from the sandboxed solution.

**Office 365**
On Office 365 you have the possibility of creating a so called Provider hosted App which with the right permissions will give you the power to do what you want.

For a guide see [Self-Service Site Provisioning using Apps for SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/04/04/self-service-site-provisioning-using-apps-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Comment: I am trying to implement it in cloud (Office365), so I dont think farm solutions are an option. What other approaches can I try? I have been  suggested to use WSS. Do you have any insight on that?

Comment: See the section I added on Office 365. Using WSS would mean changing from using Office 365 to host in a completely other environment. That's a whole other discussion.

Comment: I shall try implementing provider hosted apps and get back to you. Thanks.